# Origin of world languages

Tags: historical-linguistics

I am currently setting to investigate on a subject in the history of languages, but as a self-taught outsider I am stuck before finding out some key words to start searching the Web.

I want to investigate the following hypothesis: the split between the most distinct language groups in today's existence may have its origin in Africa, before the colonization of the "outside world" began. The population that flowed out of Africa would have consisted of many individual bands, each with its own, very distinct language. Some of these must be the origin of all today's out-of-Africa languages, but not necessarily exactly one.

I have several related questions:

1. has this hypothesis been considered at all?
2. if yes, has it already been positively dismissed?
3. are there any key terms related to this which would be googlable?

Comment: Note that the idea that all human languages derive from a single source is an unproven hypothesis. There is no _prima facie_ reason to rule out two or more independent creations of language. I think monogenesis is likely to be true, but I'm dubious that we will ever be able to prove it.

Comment: You might have a tough time showing that a language like [Nicaraguan Sign Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicaraguan_Sign_Language) can trace its ancestry to Africa. And if NSL did spring up spontaneously then it shows that it is possible that other languages could go back to origins that arose spontaneously too.

Comment: @hippietrail Each language obviously has roots in a language which has arisen spontaneously at *some* point. My question is actually about something else: it would be "obvious" to assume that only a single language group emerged from Africa, diverging from that point on. I am entertaining the idea that today's diversity in world languages owes more to the origins within Africa than that "obvious" assumption.

Comment: This assumption is unlikely to be true as there is an enormous amount of linguistic diversity within Africa just as there is an enormous amount of DNA diversity there. It would only be true if it there were only a single migration out of Africa or if all migrations out of Africa involved speakers of the same language.

Comment: @hippietrail ... or a group of similar languages. Anyway, then you agree with the hypothesis I present in the question as highly plausible and likely. Thanks.

Comment: Umm no. I agree only that it's plausible. I did some Googling and some research came out 2-3 years ago on this hypothesis and was immediately followed by some pretty good criticisms. I didn't come up with canonical links though so just recommend Googling "Out of Africa linguistics" or such. If you can't find anything then I'll post some non-canonical links.

Comment: @hippietrail When you say "this assumption is unlikely to be true", then (if I follow you correctly) you are in effect saying that it is unlikely that only one language group emerged out of Africa. Doesn't that imply that you consider it *likely* that there are at least two today's language families such that each can trace its roots to a separate origin within Africa?

Comment: Not at all. For all we know people might not yet have had language, or all the languages spoken at that time might have died out and been replaced by new spontaneously emerging languages. The only way to know is to invent a time machine or get an answer from your favourite god.

Comment: @hippietrail BTW thanks for the googling tip, that indeed led me to on-topic links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. It's called the ["out-of-africa" theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recent_African_origin_of_modern_humans). It's a paleoanthropological hypothesis with substantial support from genetics, in particular studies on [mitochondrial DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_DNA). Much work has been done by [Luigi Luca Cavalli-Sforza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luigi_Luca_Cavalli-Sforza) and others. See his book [Genes, Peoples, and Languages](https://web.archive.org/web/20050307134942/http://www.fsbassociates.com/fsg/genespeopleslanguages.htm). The linguist [Merritt Ruhlen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merritt_Ruhlen) is one of the most important linguists to test Cavalli-Sforza's hypothesis, see the [Santa Fe Institute](http://ehl.santafe.edu/main.html) website.
2. No. But language superfamilies remain a problem.
3. All the links provided above are relevant. A further term is [diversity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language#Linguistic_diversity) (but try to google more, the Wikipedia section is not that illuminating), see also [language families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language#Language_families_of_the_World).

Concerning your specific assumption that isolated bands leaving Africa contribute to the founding of distinct language families, is, however, problematic. Diversity studies comparing African vs. non-African languages consistently show that the two major African language families [Niger-Congo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niger-Congo) and [Nilo-Saharan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilo-Saharan) are much more diverse among **themselves** than all other non-African language families **combined**. (That, by the way, is also consistent with genetic diversity: there's more genetic diversity within Africa, than in the rest of the world combined.)
This can either mean that many bands leaving Africa have not contributed to the current "gene-pool" of language(s), or it can mean that there weren't that many bands to begin with.

Personally, I believe that the latter is the more compelling assumption because it matches what is known from studies on mitochondrial DNA. See this [picture](http://www.sheppardsoftware.com/worldgeographymainpage/worldstatistics5.htm), which shows that only group L3 left Africa. This group may have been diverse, and surely consisted of different bands over a certain time span, but their genetic proximity suggests cultural proximity, and hence linguistic proximity. The assumption that members of this group used mutually incomprehensible languages is far-fetched, given that these bands weren't that large to begin with.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I was actually starting from the familiar fact of deep divergence of languages in Papua New Guinea. The language families there are as distinct as, say, French and Korean. So if just one island has this kind of diversity, my logical extension would be that it was also the case in African bands, even if they lived nearby.

Comment: I'm curious about your statement about Niger-Congo and Nilo-Saharan having more diversity among themselves than all non-African language families combined: do you have a reference to support that?

@MarkoTopolnik the time depth back to the original departure from Africa is so great that we can most likely never know any detail about the diversity of the languages spoken either in Africa or by the original migrants.

Comment: @ Gaston Ümlaut I remember reading that somewhere, and it was a reputable source. Not that that couldn't make it controversial. But I should've included the Khoi-san family as well.